# Windows - Restrict ability to run application to one service account

Tags: windows, permissions, service-accounts, executable

I've been asked to write a script that enters information from one application into another - and I've done it using a combination of Python, Selenium and Firefox (it's a temporary measure before a project to actually properly integrate the two apps).

Problem is that Firefox isn't an approved browser on our estate, Security say I can use it for this once-off purpose if I restrict Firefox to the service account running the script.

So my question is, what options do I have in Windows to restrict an application to a specific account in Windows?

Can I just change the permissions of the .exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And Stack Exchange requires 30 characters..

Comment: so why the "es 30 characters.."?

Comment: because " And Stack Exchange requir" would only satisfy the servers, not the humans. :)

Comment: OK thanks, just guessed it would be more complicated!